# MO account continuity

Tags: support

My email account was virtually destroyed by a computer virus, on my Mac. Thus, I stay away from this whole thing by not even using my regular Mac unix account. Instead, I use a Mac guest account (a great inconvenience), I've created a new email account, then I subscribed to MO again, this time as *Wlod AA*.

Ma old (and still present) MO account is *Włodzimierz Holsztyński*. How do I preserve my MO continuity without being active under the old account name? I'd like now to use account name *Wlod AA*.

---

PS. How do I create a *new unix user* (i.e. a new unix account) on Mac? (It used to be very simple but Apple loves to turn their computers more and more into toys rather than computers). My macOS Sierra is Version 10.12.5.

Comment: I tried "how do i make a new unix user on my mac sierra" as a web search and got what looked like a reasonable answer.  Gerhard "Maybe It's Reasonable For You" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: new unix account (any Mac account is a unix account): System Preferences  > Users & Groups > Click the lock to make changes > Login as an administrator > +

Comment: Account continuity? Does that mean that the preimage of every open neighborhood of the user is an open neighborhood of the person behind the keyboard?

Comment: I think he means contiunity.  Sort of like a partition of unity, except he wants to preserve his conti across account breaks.  Gerhard "Doesn't Suffer an Inedtity Crisis" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, you're wonderful! I followed your directions, it was smooth. If we ever meet, a coffee or beer is on me or both. (This is my second similar offering I've made in this thread; the first one was for Todd).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as your MO account goes, scroll to the bottom of this page to the gray box, and click on 'contact us' which you will find in the upper right of that box. There you can reach Stack Exchange Community Management; you should explain that you want your old account merged into your new account. They are the only ones who can perform an account merger.

Comment: Todd, thank you for your answer. I am of such a low repute that I cannot upvote you. Thus, if we ever meet, a coffee or beer is on me or both.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help in small ways, Włodzimierz. It would also be a pleasure to meet over drinks some day (something I feel towards many I know through MO).